# Как выполнить команду в приложении, запущенном через Apache Commons Exec?

Tags: apache, консоль, gui, java, exec

*Помогите пожалуйста. Ответ Barmaley не устраивает. Я только учусь программировать на java, поэтому нужен пример...*

Пытаюсь сделать GUI для консольной программы. Запуск идёт через Apache Exec:

```
Executor exec = new DefaultExecutor();
InputStream is = new InputStream() {

    @Override
    public int read() throws IOException {
        throw new UnsupportedOperationException("Not supported yet.");
    }
};
LogOutputStream os = new LogOutputStream() {

    @Override
    protected void processLine(String line, int i) {
        // Вывод лога консольной программы программы в JTextPane моей графической оболочки
        addLine(line);
    }
};
exec.setStreamHandler(new PumpStreamHandler(null, os, is));

// Команда на запуск программы. Например:
final CommandLine cl = new CommandLine("java -jar myConsoleProgram.jar");

Thread t = new Thread() {

    public void run() {
        try {
            int exitvalue = exec.execute(cl);
        } catch (ExecuteException ex) {
        } catch (IOException ex) {
        }
    }
};
t.setName("JarInputStreamThread");
t.start();
```

Консольная программа запускается из моей графической оболочки, записывает лог в JTextPane в моей программе и ждёт ввода команд от пользователя. 
Подскажите, как отправить команду в эту консольную программу? Насколько я понял, нужно использовать InputStream (is), но как именно?

**UPDATE:** [Немного изменил код](http://jsfiddle.net/7soft/GGVfv/2/). Команды, правда, не выполняет, но судя по статьям в интернете, код отправки команд должен выглядеть примерно так...

**UPDATE 2:** [Подобный вопрос на StackOverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8785636/apache-commons-exec-run-interactive-terminal-application)

Answer (score 1):

Вы как то путаетесь в показаниях: если у вас консольная прога, то причем здесь GUI и `JTextPane`? Очевидно речь идет о свинговой проге.

Раз так, то надо где-то в интерфейс вставить `JTextField` с кнопкой `JButton`. Юзер будет писать командную строку в `JTextField` и топтать кнопку. Обработчик кнопки возьмет строку и засунет его в ваш `CommandLine`

**Update**

> Консольная программа после запуска
> ждёт ввода команд (например, help или
> stop). Как запустить эти команды
> нажатием соответствующей кнопки в моей
> граф. оболочке?

Вводите команды в `JTextField` и по нажатию кнопки пишите на `System.out` - так консольная прога получит `help` там или `stop` (как консольная прога она по идее должна ждать ввод на `System.in`)

Comment: Barmaley, попробую ещё раз. 
Есть консольная программа на java (не моя). Её редактировать нельзя, так как бывают обновления. Но можно написать графический интерфейс, чем я и занимаюсь. Текстовое поле и кнопки есть, я дал только код, который запускает консольную программу из моей графической оболочки и выводит её лог в нужном мне виде.
Консольная программа после запуска ждёт ввода команд (например, help или stop). Как запустить эти команды нажатием соответствующей кнопки в моей граф. оболочке?

Comment: Насколько я понимаю, System.out и System.in - это ввод/вывод моей графической оболочки, а не той программы, которая из неё запускается. Если я ошибаюсь, то можно пример?